# how to fix require_one startup.php

Tags: php, require

how to fix

> Warning:
>   require_once(/var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/batikabaz_com/system/startup.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\batikabaz_com\index.php on line 17
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   '/var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/batikabaz_com/system/startup.php'
>   (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\batikabaz_com\index.php on line 17

Comment: Please share your project details: structure and somde code would help.

Answer (score 0):

You could construct the path relative to current directory, like this:

```
require_once(__DIR__. '/system/startup.php');
```